# Create array from map in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I have this **HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in entityL">
  <td>{{row.Name}}</td>
  <td>{{row.Surname}}</td>
  <td>{{row.Initials}}</td>
  <td>{{row.RolDivisionList.Name}}</td>
</tr>
```

And I want to get an array with all those values in Protractor, and I must access to the first one.

I tried with this **Protractor function in a page object**

```
this.getAllUsers = function() {
  var userList = element.all(by.repeater('row in entityL'));

  return userList.map(function(tr) {    
    return {
      name: tr.element(by.binding('row.Name')).getText(),
      surname: tr.element(by.binding('row.Surname')).getText(),
      initials: tr.element(by.binding('row.Initials')).getText(),
      rolDivision: tr.element(by.binding('row.RolDivisionList.Name')).getText()
    };
  });
};
```

I get a **result** like this

```
[ 
   { name : 'Name1', surname : 'Surname1', initials : 'Initials1', rolDivision : 'Rol1' }, 
   { name : 'Name2', surname : 'Surname2', initials : 'Initials2', rolDivision : 'Rol2' } 
]
```

But I can't access to it's values, I tried `array[0]`, `array[0]['name']`, `array[0].name`, `array.get(0)`... and nothing works. I also tried to wrap the `return` inside the `map` with `[]` but didn't worked either.

The fact is that **I just want the first user**, but I just can't achieve it and must return all of them, so if you know how to return just the first to the test that would be great too.

This is the **test code** (just the `it`):

```
iit('should return the first user', function() {    
  expect(userListPage.getAllUsers()[0]['name']).toBe('Name1');
});
```

## New experiments

I tried some experiments with the previous code, trying to learn about how Protractor works and this is what I got.

I will use the previous HTML and the new **Protractor functions in a page object**

```
var UserListPage = function() {
  this.userList = element.all(by.repeater('row in entityL'));

  this.getFirstUser = function() {
    return {
      name: element(by.binding('row.Name')).getText(),
      surname: element(by.binding('row.Surname')).getText(),
      initials: element(by.binding('row.Initials')).getText(),
      rolDivision: element(by.binding('row.RolDivisionList.Name')).getText()
    };
  };

  this.getUserData = function (tr) {
    return {
      name: tr.element(by.binding('row.Name')).getText(),
      surname: tr.element(by.binding('row.Surname')).getText(),
      initials: tr.element(by.binding('row.Initials')).getText(),
      rolDivision: tr.element(by.binding('row.RolDivisionList.Name')).getText()
    };
  };

  this.getAllUsers = function() {    
    return this.userList.map(function(tr) {      
      return {
        name: tr.element(by.binding('row.Name')).getText(),
        surname: tr.element(by.binding('row.Surname')).getText(),
        initials: tr.element(by.binding('row.Initials')).getText(),
        rolDivision: tr.element(by.binding('row.RolDivisionList.Name')).getText()
      };
    });
  };
};

module.exports = UserListPage;
```

And now the test block with all the experiments

```
it('should test things', function() {
  userListPage.getAllUsers().then(function(array) {
    //First user array
    expect(array[0]).toEqual("");
    //Name of the first user
    expect(array[0].name).toEqual("");
  });

  //Array with all users
  expect(userListPage.getAllUsers()).toEqual("");

  //Name of the first user
  expect(userListPage.getAllUsers().name).toEqual("");

  //undefined
  expect(userListPage.getAllUsers()[0]).toEqual("");

  //Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
  expect(userListPage.getAllUsers()[0].name).toEqual("");



  //.then is not a function
  userListPage.getFirstUser().then(function(array) {});

  //ERROR Process out of memory
  expect(userListPage.getFirstUser()).toEqual("");

  //Name of the first user
  expect(userListPage.getFirstUser().name).toEqual("");

  //undefined
  expect(userListPage.getFirstUser()[0]).toEqual("");

  //Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
  expect(userListPage.getFirstUser()[0].name).toEqual("");



  //.then is not a function
  userListPage.getUserData(userListPage.userList.first()).then(function(array){});

  //ERROR Process out of memory
  expect(userListPage.getUserData(userListPage.userList.first())).toEqual("");

  //Name of the first user
  expect(userListPage.getUserData(userListPage.userList.first()).name).toEqual("");

  //undefined
  expect(userListPage.getUserData(userListPage.userList.first())[0]).toEqual("");

  //Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
  expect(userListPage.getUserData(userListPage.userList.first())[0].name).toEqual("");

});
```

It seems strange to me that this `expect(userListPage.getFirstUser()).toEqual("");` stop Protractor with an error and this `expect(userListPage.getFirstUser().name).toEqual("");` return the correct value.

Can someone also explain why this things happens?

**PD: Should I put all this in a new question?**

Comment: Have you tried to get it using `element.all(by.binding('row.Name')).first();` ?

Comment: @GirishSortur That works too, and is even better using `element(by.binding('row.Name'))`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it without the need to use `.map()` function, if there are no elements with the same binding in the DOM. Protractor has inbuilt element locator for `ng-binding`. Here's how -

```
element(by.binding('row.Name'));
```

However, if there are more html elements with same ng-binding attribute, then use ElementArrayFinder to get the element -

```
element.all(by.binding('row.Name')).first();
```

Another way would be get the element using its parent -

```
element.all(by.repeater('row in entityL')).element(by.binding('row.Name')); //Get only the first element with that binding
```

About your new question with research, your `expect(userListPage.getFirstUser()).toEqual("");` returns an error because the function `getFirstUser()` is returning an object and you have to get the key of the object to access the key's value, in your case you should use `.name` to get the name of the user. So `expect(userListPage.getFirstUser().name).toEqual("");` returns a proper answer. [More on objects in Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp).

Hope it helps.

Comment: But why the first `expect` in the script is showing the object as an array and the others can't?

Comment: which first `expect` are you talking about? Can you please explain where the error is?

Comment: This `expect(array[0]).toEqual("");` inside `userListPage.getAllUsers().then`, in the first line of the `it`. That is an object too and it can be compared and is showed as a string when the result is shown on console

Comment: That's because the `map()` function returns an array back. [Documentation on map function](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map). But the rest of your functions don't implement `map()` method and so you don't get array back for them instead the object that you are returning manually.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with `map` but since you are only interested in the first item, you can use `all` in conjunction with `first` or `get`:

```
  function getUserData (tr) {
    return {
      name: tr.element(by.binding('row.Name')).getText(),
      surname: tr.element(by.binding('row.Surname')).getText(),
      initials: tr.element(by.binding('row.Initials')).getText(),
      rolDivision: tr.element(by.binding('row.RolDivisionList.Name')).getText()
    };
  }

  var userList = element.all(by.repeater('row in entityL'));
  var item = getUserData(userList.first());

  expect(item.name).toEqual('Name1');
```

Alternately, you can `then` off of your `map` to resolve to the name of the first item:

```
var name = element.all(by.repeater('row in entityL'))
  .map(getUserData)
  .then(function (mappedArray) {
    return mappedArray[0].name
  });

expect(name).toEqual('Name1');
```

Comment: The first option works when I call only the name, but if I try this `expect(item.name + ' ' + item.surname).toEqual('Name1 Surname1')` it returns `Expected '[object Object] [object Object]' to be 'Name1 Surname1'.` I tried adding `toString()` but it didn't work.

Comment: That is because both of those properties are actually promises so you are trying to add two promise objects together. If you need to get the results of both and add them together you will have to resolve them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nick ;)